# how to determine ulimits - linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

how to determine ulimits (linux)?

Im using ubuntu 16.04, 
kernel version 4.4.0-21-generic

I set the nofile to maximum for root (in /etc/security/limits.conf)
the line is: * hard nofile NUMBER
according to file /proc/sys/fs/file-max
the value is : 32854728

when Im running the command ulimit -a
i found that the limitation is 1024.

i tested it , and i found that the highest value of max open file is 1048575.
If I set it to higher value the limit is 1024.

how to determine ulimit of openfiles? why I can't set it to higher limit than 1048575?

Comment: You are confusing per-user/per-process limits (in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and checked via `ulimit`) with system-wide limits like in `proc/sys/fs/file-max`. These are two different concepts. Have you logged out and back in after modifying `limits.conf`? Have you tried `ulimit -n 1048575`?

Comment: I want to grant root the value in   /proc/sys/fs/file-max , when i set the limit on virtual machines that the system-wide limit is small it works. When i set the limit on physical servers that the system-wide limit is big number ( such as 32854728) i saw the limit is 1024 even if i change in /etc/security/limits.conf and login again (even restart the server), any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the maximum number of file handles for the entire system, run:

cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max

To determine the current usage of file handles, run:

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
1154    133     8192
|   |  |
|   |      |
|         |       maximum open file descriptors
   |   total free allocated file descriptors
total allocated file descriptors
(the number of file descriptors allocated since boot)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, which is about `ulimits` - per-user and/or per-process limits, not system-wide limits.

Comment: how to determine if I need to change the default ulimits per user/process? On the one hand , i dont want that application won't have enough resources. On the other hand I dont wont to set ulimited values